# Vuejs cache global variable

Tags: vue.js

I created a global variable in `main.js` like so :

```
Vue.prototype.$foo = []

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Is there a way to cache this `$foo` variable to access it on page refresh?

Comment: use localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data persistence can be done with the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) (including `localStorage`) or [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). `localStorage` is probably the simplest for storing string values (e.g., *stringified* arrays/objects).

To restore the value, use `JSON.parse()` on the `localStorage` value:

```js
Vue.prototype.$foo = localStorage.foo
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.foo)
  : {} /* default value */
```

To save the value, use `JSON.stringify()` on the value to be stored:

```js
localStorage.foo = JSON.stringify(/* new value */)
```

Comment: Thank you! In the end I used a similar, albeit not as elegant solution.